# Does classloaders and class objects start in Young generation?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

Here is the [documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation) that I am using as reference. I know that class information is stored in perm gen space. The perm gen space is populated by objects that survive eden and tenured generations. Is it correct to conclude that class objects start from eden generation?

Please assume HotSpot JVM for discussion. Not sure if the answer depends on version. If it does, would love to know that as well.

Comment: To answer this precisely you'd need to specify the jvm version and the platform it's being run on.

Answer (score 1):

The term *permanent generation* is misleading. No object is ever promoted out of or into the permanent generation. The permanent generation is treated different than the young and tenured generations where objects can promote from the former to the latter. An object starting in eden is therefore never allocated into the permanent generation.

Thus, the answer is no. However, note that from Java 8 on, the permanent generation was resolved and its data is now stored in the so-called meta space.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?